# Getting CellID or other location data on J2ME platform

Tags: java-me

Is there a universal way we can retrieve CellID in J2ME or what's the usual standard practice to get those information ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the Cellid is still limited by mobile phone platform, Sign-certificate and Operator and different on most mobile phones.

The links does cover most (not all, imho) ways to get the cellID from the device properties.
[link](http://www.easywms.com/easywms/?q=en/node/3589)